# WP 8.1 Current user location return from GetGeopositionAsync always several hundred meters away from the actual location

Tags: windows-phone-8.1

When I tested my app which uses Geolocator.GetGeopositionAsync to get the current user's location, the returned coordinate is always several hundred meters away from the actual location, even if the returned PositionSource is from GPS with an accuracy within 10 meters.

I was using Lumia 930 as a testing tool.
The following is my code:

```
//get current location
var geo = new Geolocator { DesiredAccuracy = PositionAccuracy.High, DesiredAccuracyInMeters = 10};   
var currentLocation = await geo.GetGeopositionAsync();

//mark location on the map.
var point=currentLocation .Coordinate.Point;
MapIcon MapIcon1 = new MapIcon();
MapIcon1.Location = point;
MapIcon1.NormalizedAnchorPoint = new Point(0.5, 1.0);
MapIcon1.Title = "I'm here";
MapControl1.MapElements.Add(MapIcon1);
await MapControl1.TrySetViewAsync(point, 18D, 0, 0, MapAnimationKind.Bow);
```

Is anyone has an idea why is this?

Comment: Does the built-in maps app show you at the correct location? Does [this situation](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/23662959/maps-for-china-which-is-correct-satellite-or-default-street-map-does-that-m) apply to you?

Comment: The link doesn't apply to my situation. I'v tested the coordinate on google's map and it gave the same mark spot as it is on my lumia's built in default map.